# java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel not closing properly

Tags: java, sockets, garbage-collection, nio

I have a `java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel` which I initialised as follows:

```
while(true)
{
    ServerSocketChannel channel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    InetSocketAddress serverSocket = new InetSocketAddress(host,port);
    channel.bind(serverSocket);
    SocketChannel ch = channel.accept();

    // Later on when I have read off data from a client, I want to shut this 
    // connection down and restart listening.
    channel.socket().close(); //Just trying to close the associated socket 
    // too because earlier approaches failed
    channel.close();
}
```

When I send the first message from client it is successfully delivered to server and the client program *exits*. Then trouble begins. When I initialise the client again and try to 
establish at the same port and address of the server as I did the first time, I get a

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect

exception even though I closed the associated channel/socket. 
I have been renewing the `ServerSocketChannel` and `InetSocketAddress`objects because as my client instance has to shut down after a write, I have to disengage that channel and since I cannot reuse a channel after it has been closed, I have to make a new object everytime. My theory is since the `channel` reference is reassigned each time, the orphaned object becomes GC meat, but since the close() method apparently is not working properly, the channel is still alive and until GC collects it my port will be hogged.
Nevertheless I tried keeping the initialisation of `ServerSocketChannel` and `InetSocketAddress` objects before the while loop, but this did not help, and the same exception occurred after the first write, as before.

```
 ServerSocketChannel channel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
 InetSocketAddress serverSocket = new InetSocketAddress(host,port);
 channel.bind(serverSocket);

 while (true)
 {
    SocketChannel ch = channel.accept();
    //read from a client
 }
```

For clarity , here is how I connect from the client:

```
        SocketChannel ch=SocketChannel.open();
        ch.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8077));
        InetSocketAddress address=new InetSocketAddress("localhost",8079);
                    //the address and port of the server
        System.out.print(ch.connect(address));
        ByteBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
        buf.clear();
        buf.put("Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooo".getBytes());
        buf.flip();
        while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
            ch.write(buf);
        }
        ch.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing client and server. Normally, server starts only once and `bind`s to s port. Usually, there's no need to `close` there anything as the port gets freed when the program exits. Obviously, you must close the `Socket`s obtained by `ServerSocket.accept()`, but that's another story.

I guess you've got confused by your variable names (just like it happened to me as I started with this). Try to call all things according to their type, here was Hungarian really helpful for me.

---

The [code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/RebindDemo.java) I wrote for testing this is long, stupid, and boring. But it seems to work.

Comment: This definitely seemed to be the case in vanilla sockets. However in nio things seem strange. I will try to pay more attention to the variable names.

Comment: I'm not sure if I knew what I was talking about... So I tried it out and binding and closing `ServerSocketChannel` seems to work. Even some communication does. I'll link it when I polish it a bit.

Comment: If in your trial the server could receive traffic more than once from clients (after shutdown of a client another connects etc), I would appreciate if you mention how it was done.

Comment: @zafar142003: It was done in a very stupid way... and without any channels on the client. See the added link.

Comment: @maartinus You used the vanilla sockets in your client, that is why I presume the problems did not occur in your case. Maybe I should revert to the plain sockets too in my client code.

Comment: @zafar142003: Maybe... but are you sure you want to bind again and again?

Comment: @maartinus: I have given my existing client code in my question as well, if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: I would prefer not binding again as long as client could reconnect.

Comment: I updated my example with `SocketChannel` on the client side. AFAIK binding is expensive and doing it for each request means you loose all the speed advantage of channels.

Comment: In your code, you did not reconnect the client. Run the server in a loop, and after the client exits for the first time rerun the client and see if the server is able to listen.

Comment: It is working fine now. You were right, while initialising the client I was binding it unnecessarily to an address which was not freed while exiting. I still don't know how to unbind it, but it turns out that that step can be avoided. Thanks:)

Comment: I updated my example and it works. No idea what client binding is good for... ignorance is a bliss. :D It's all pretty verbose and complicated already.

Comment: Haha. That is why Java is not-so-revered for its verbosity!

Comment: @zafar142003 No-one who has ever programmed sockets in C would agree with that. Any verbosity here was programmer-induced. And you're mistaken about the error. The problem was excess *server* binding. Just create and bind the server socket before the accept loop.

Comment: @EJP: I did try that. At the end of my question, I had stated that the exception did not go away if I did what you suggest (bind before the loop). The problem was that I was binding my client to socket before connecting to the server. When I removed that call, the problem vanished.
Regarding verbosity, I would say that I find that helpful in *most* of the cases. But this wasn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be helpful to do:

channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true);

Search for information about this option to learn more.

Answer (score -3):

do ch.close() as well to GC the client socket.

Comment: You mean apart from channel.close() and channel.socket().close()?

Comment: `ch.close()` neither causes nor enables GC on the client socket. It does, however, close it.